# limit of $\int_{[0,n]\times \mathbb[0,n]}e^{-(x^3+y^2)}dxdy$, as $n\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral, polar-coordinates

I have to compute the limit as $n\to\infty$ of the following: $$\int_{[0,n]\times \mathbb[0,n]}e^{-(x^3+y^2)}dxdy$$ To study the integrability I have though to say:
$$\int_{[0,n]\times \mathbb[0,n]}e^{-(x^3+y^2)}dxdy=\int_{\mathbb{R}^+\times \mathbb{R}^+}e^{-(x^3+y^2)}\chi_{[0,n]\times[0,n]}dxdy=$$
From Fubini then I have
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(x^3+y^2)}dxdy=\int_{1}^{\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-(x^3+y^2)}dxdy+\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}e^{-(x^3+y^2)}dxdy$$
In $[0,1]$ there are no problems of convergence. In $[1,\infty]$ I can say $e^{-x^3-y^2}\leq e^{-x^2-y^2}$, so:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-(x^3+y^2)}dxdy\leq \int_{1}^{\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy$$
for this last integral I have thought to use polar coordinates to prove the convergence...but I can't fix the interval of $r$ and $\theta$, considering $x>1$ and $y>1$.

**Questions:** 1) Extremes of integration in Polar coordinates
2)My idea is right or there is a better way of working?

Comment: There is no problem in the initial integral. The function is continue on a bounded box.

Comment: By the way your integral decomposition is not correct.

Comment: @Youem why is not correct??

Comment: $\mathbb R_{+}^2 = [0,1]^2 \cup [0,1]\times [1,\infty) \cup [1,\infty) \times [0,1] \cup [1, \infty)\times [1,\infty)$

Comment: Moreover I have to consider that the limit depends on $n$ that is also on integration extremes. So I have to trasform the integral using the characterstic function, not?

Comment: @Youem ...sorry but I have decomposed each $(0,\infty)$ in $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$...I don't understand the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146492/discussion-between-jin-and-youem).

Comment: First you don't need to decompose. Second when you decompose each $(0, \infty)$ don't forget the cross integrals.

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you are concerned about is integrability, then without knowing how to evaluate the Gaussian integral $\iint e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,dx\,dy$, you can use the simple bound $e^x \ge 1+x^m/m!$ for any $m\ge 1$ and $x\ge 0$ to get
$$
e^{-x^3-y^2} \le e^{-(x^2+y^2)} \le \frac{1}{1+(m!)^{-1}(x^2+y^2)^m}, \qquad x,y\ge 1.
$$
You should be able to verify in an elementary fashion that the latter function is integrable on $\mathbb R^2$ provided we choose $m>2$ (say) by dividing $\mathbb R^2$ into level sets of $x^2+y^2$.

Comment: Thanks! this works alos if I directly bound the first function? I mean $e^{-x^3+y^2}<\frac{1}{1+(m!)^{-1}(x^3+y^2)^m}$?

Answer (score 0):

You have that for fixed $y$, $x\mapsto e^{-x^3-y^2}$ is integrable on $\mathbb R_{+}$ and $$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^3-y^2}\mathrm d x = \left(\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^3}\mathrm d x\right) e^{-y^2}.$$ Now the function $$y\mapsto \left(\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^3}\mathrm d x\right) e^{-y^2}$$ is clearly integrable on $\mathbb R_{+}$. This proves that $(x, y) \mapsto e^{-x^3-y^2}$ is integrable on $\mathbb R_{+}^2$.